# Respondi a uma pesquisa do Stack Overflow e agora o sistema não para de me agradecer

Tags: bug

Acabei de responder a uma [pesquisa](https://stackoverflow.az1.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/SV_b14eaLcRaiLlZMF) e agora, em toda página que entro, aparece esse aviso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Isso acontece tanto no site principal quanto no Meta: a cada página visitada, o aviso aparece novamente. Mesmo se eu clicar no <kbd>x</kbd>, ao visitar outra página do site (ou recarregar a mesma), o aviso reaparece.

Sei que a pesquisa deve ser importante e tal, mas só precisava me agradecer uma vez...

---

Estou usando Windows 10 Home e Chrome 89.0.4389.82.

Comment: Não consegui reproduzir. Vou perguntar o _clichê_, mas talvez resolva... :P Você tentou limpar os _cookies_ e os dados do site no geral?

Comment: @LuizFelipe Ainda não. Estou esperando uma resposta, pois [também postei no meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/362018/401803) e inclusive lá tb teve um que disse que não aconteceu com ele, então não sei se é algo geral ou só aqui. De qualquer forma, vou aguardar...

Comment: Eu não tive esse problema também.

Comment: E agora parou de acontecer, sem eu precisar fazer nada (não mexi em nenhuma config do browser/SO, nada...)

Comment: É que o sistema "muito agradecido"